# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'money' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

в боте есть лотерея, участи в которой стоит 5 монет. 1% шанс на выигрыш в 100 монет, 10% шанс на выигрыш в 20 монет, иначе ничего. но когда я запускаю бот,
мне пишет :

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'money' referenced before
> assignment.

код:

```
import telebot
import random

money = 100

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

keyboard1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True)
keyboard1.row('/mymoney', '/info')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['lotery'])
def lotery(message):
    money = money - 5
    if random.randint(1, 100) == 2 or random.randint(1, 100) == 3 or random.randint(1, 100) == 4 or random.randint(1, 100) == 5 or random.randint(1, 100) == 6:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Забирай свои 20 дуркоинов.', reply_markup=keyboard1)              
        money = money + 20                                                                                                  
    elif random.randint(1, 100) == 7 or random.randint(1, 100) == 8 or random.randint(1, 100) == 9 or random.randint(1, 100) == 10 or random.randint(1, 100) == 11:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Забирай свои 20 дуркоинов.', reply_markup=keyboard1)              
        money = money + 20  
    elif random.randint(1, 100) == 1:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'ты выиграл. Забирай 100 дуркоинов.', reply_markup=keyboard1)
        money = money + 100
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты проиграл.', reply_markup=keyboard1)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Начинаю работу.', reply_markup=keyboard1)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['mymoney'])
def my_money(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'У тебя %s дуркоинов' % money, reply_markup=keyboard1)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['info'])
def info(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Банк Республики Дурка. /mymoney - мой счёт. /lotery - лотерея. Цена билета - 5 дуркоинов.', reply_markup=keyboard1)


        

bot.polling()
```

Comment: В какой строке ошибка?

Comment: ошибка в функции lotery